How to decrypts ciphertexts in a single go from ciphertexts which were encrypted by separately using AES?
I try encryption-decryption using AES with 256 key on the platform of OpenSSL v3 with C++.
 bool CryptographicUtils::encrypt(unsigned char* plainText, int size, unsigned char** pOutCipherText, int &cipherTextSize)
{   
    int cipherTextLength(size + AES_BLOCK_SIZE);
    *pOutCipherText = new unsigned char[cipherTextLength];
    if(nullptr == *pOutCipherText)
    {   
        std::cout << std::endl << "encrypt:mem alloc (for pOutCipherText) has failed." << std::endl;
        handleErrors();
        return false;
    }   

    //performs a symmetric encryption operation on a chunk of data   
    if (1 != EVP_EncryptUpdate(m_pCipherContext, *pOutCipherText, &cipherTextLength, plainText, size))
    {
        std::cout << std::endl << "encrypt:EVP_EncryptUpdate has failed." << std::endl;
        handleErrors();
        return false;
    }
    //handles any necessary padding
    int paddingLength(0);
    if (1 != EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(m_pCipherContext, (*pOutCipherText + cipherTextLength), &paddingLength))
    {
        std::cout << std::endl << "encrypt:EVP_EncryptFinal_ex has failed." << std::endl;
         handleErrors();
         return false;
    }
    cipherTextLength += paddingLength;
    cipherTextSize = cipherTextLength;   
    return true;
}

    void decrypt(unsigned char* encryptedData, int encryptedDataSize )
    {
    
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX* ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
        if (!ctx)
        {
            handleErrors();
            return;
        } 
    
         std::cout << std::endl << "Decrypting ciphertext using AES 256"<< std::endl;
        if (1 != EVP_DecryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), NULL, Key_, iv_))
        {
            handleErrors();
            return;
        } 
    
        //initialize a decryption operation
        int decryptedDataBufferSize = encryptedDataSize + AES_BLOCK_SIZE;
        int decryptedDataSize = 0;
        
        //Save decrypted data here
unsigned char* decrypted_buffer = new unsigned char[decryptedDataBufferSize];

        if (1 != EVP_DecryptUpdate(ctx, decrypted_buffer, &decryptedDataBufferSize, encryptedData, encryptedDataSize))
        {
            std::cout << std::endl << "EVP_DecryptUpdate failed" << std::endl;
            handleErrors();
            return;
        }
    
        decryptedDataSize += decryptedDataBufferSize;
        std::cout << std::endl << "Decryption stage (EVP_DecryptUpdate) completed. Size of Decrypted data: " << decryptedDataBufferSize << std::endl;
    
        int padLength(0);
        //finalize the decryption process and handle any necessary padding
        if (1 != EVP_DecryptFinal_ex(ctx, decrypted_buffer + encryptedDataSize, &padLength))
        {
            std::cout << std::endl << "EVP_DecryptFinal_ex failed" << std::endl;
            handleErrors();
            return;
        }
    
        decryptedDataSize += padLength;
}

I have invoked the above method to generate the ciphertext from two chunks of data separately.
Chunk 1 is 1024 bytes of plaintext and it produced a ciphertext1 of 1040 bytes(these additional 16 bytes may be padding)
Chunk 2 is 726 bytes of plaintext and it produced a ciphertext2 of 726 bytes.
For decrypting, these cipher text can be decrypted separately.
But I am checking the options whether it is technically feasible to combine the ciphertexts and decrypt in a single stretch? Have any one tried this out?
I tried one sample in C++ where i combined these ciphertexts and decrypt in a single stretch. But there were some DLE characters in the decrypted output when compared to actual plan texts.
Thanks, Prasanth

For single-step decryption with regular AES/CBC/PKCS7, 1. during encryption padding must be disabled for all plaintext chunks except the last one, and 2. the last block of ciphertext chunk n must be used as IV for encryption of plaintext chunk n+1 (for the latter, see CBC scheme).
